# os.path.join not finding file in specified directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a game and have a function that checks for valid audio files before attempting to load them. The function looks like this:

```
def load_sound(name):
    class NoneSound:
        def play(self): pass
    if not pygame.mixer or not pygame.mixer.get_init():
        return NoneSound()
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    try:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(fullname)
    except pygame.error:
        print('Cannot load sound:', fullname)
        raise SystemExit
    return sound
```

The object being passed into this function is simply:

```
fire = load_sound("sounds/laser.wav")
```

The py file is in a folder that also contains a folder called data. Nested in that are several folders, one of which is "sounds". The laser.wav file is in that folder:

[image: Project folder nesting]

The function fails with an error:

```
Cannot load sound: data\sounds/laser.wav
```

Why is python adding a \ after data when it should be a /?
When I load files directly, they load fine, such as this:

```
music = pygame.mixer.music.load("data/music/Zone_66_Theme.ogg")
```

More specifically, why is the file not found?

Comment: ``\`` is the default Windows path separator; you can safely mix ``\`` and `/` in Windows paths.

Comment: O.K. That still fails to explain why the file is not found when it clearly is there.

Comment: That's why that was a comment, not an answer. :-) It could be that `pygame` is less flexible in that regard.

Comment: What happens when you use `load_sound('sounds\\laser.wav')` instead?

Comment: Did you try to debug it, even by printing the path's actual string? It can be useful sometimes. You can also try to use [os.path.abspath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) - which should give you a normalized path defined by your OS. Hope that helps.

Comment: remove your custom try catch and see what except the module raises (paste that here)

Comment: Well, it seems like there's a mismatch finding the correct path and that maybe, just maybe he needs to normalize the path to the file so python will actually fetch it.  
and isn't it a bad idea in first place to hardcode the file's path?

Comment: Even if I replace the call with `fire = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/laser.wav")` or evev `fire = pygame.mixer.Sound("data/sounds/laser.wav")` it still errors with `pygame.error: Unable to open file 'sounds/laser.wav'`

Comment: It still fails if I bypass it and instead use `fire = pygame.mixer.Sound("sounds/laser.wav")` or `fire = pygame.mixer.Sound("data/sounds/laser.wav")`

Comment: To answer your question Martijn Pieters, if I use `load_sound('sounds\\laser.wav')` instead I still get `Cannot load sound: data\sounds\laser.wav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the code is good, it's the WAV file that is the issue. I converted the laser.wav into an OGG file and now the file loads fine.